# What is Waiting Time when a website load in broswer?

Tags: pagespeed, yslow, speed-test

I have web application, which takes long time(10-12 sec) at initial load (esp., the launch page) and gets faster after that less than a 600ms, So how can we improve it ? and What is Waiting Time when a website load in broswer ? [image]

The site is build upon ASP.net and Microsoft SQL Server database.

Comment: I would assume the wait time is the time between request and response. The time it takes the request to travel over the wire + time taken for server processing + time for first response packet to travel over the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Firefox/Firebug. You can check the [Firebug wiki](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Timeline) for a definition of the different request phases. (Other browsers have similar names.)

In your case, Waiting reflects the time between request and response, as Brad mentioned. That row you highlighted shows a wait of 12.66s for the server to start responding, then just 6ms spent receiving the data.

To resolve that you'll need to debug within your application itself. Tools like YSlow and PageSpeed are good for the front-end components (JS, CSS, images, etc.) but won't help you diagnose the initial page load speed directly.

Comment: i used Code pro filer to check for the issues .. found out that there were many database calls in the code....